# Tailwind css border color not working on web page

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I am just trying with tailwindcss, I got stuck at very basic thing. I tried different tailwindcss's utility classed and it worked. But now I am stuck at border-color

```
<div className="px-4 border-gray-900 border-solid">
   <a href="#" className="block font-semibold">Menu1</a>
   <a href="#" className="block ">Menu2</a>
   <a href="#" className="block ">Menu3</a>
   <a href="#" className="block ">Login</a>
</div>
```

I can inspect the elements and it is crossed in inspect element which means somehow it is not being applied to dom.

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
        secondary: 'var(--color-secondary)',
        negative: 'var(--color-negative)',
        positive: 'var(--color-positive)',
        'primary-background': 'var(--background-primary)',
        'sec-background': 'var(--background-sec)',
        'primary-text': 'var(--color-text-primary)',
      },
    },
    backgroundColor: (theme) => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
    }),
    borderColor: (theme) => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
    }),
  },
  variants: {
    backgroundColor: ['active'],
    borderStyle: ['responsive'],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This is how my tailwind.config.js looks like

Attaching an image [image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Like you see in inspector, you defined only border color but not [border width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp). Because it is 0px, it is invisible ;)

You need to change it to

```
class="border border-gray-800"
```

"border" will by default mean `border-width: 1px` so if you need thicker use for example

```
class="border-2 border-gray-800"
```

or if you wanna it only on one side

```
class="border-right border-gray-800"
```

More in [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width).

Answer (score 8):

Nothing was working for me until I added the `border-style: solid` using `border-solid`. I had to explicitly set `border-0` though, else it will be applied to all directions.

```html
<div className="border-0 border-b-2 border-solid border-b-red-600">Bottom border</div>
```

I am using `"tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"`

Comment: this worked for me! thanks!

Comment: Same results here, `border-style: solid;` was the missing ingredient.

Comment: Strange how this worked for me too. I have never needed that before with tailwind. how can you make it so you do not need `border-solid`

Comment: For me this was the solution. My guess is that within the project I'm working is a legacy css framework in use ant design and i would guess this has inferrences that make `border-solid`neccesary in such cases

Comment: this worked for me too. So now need to first make all the borders width 0 and then bottom will work?

Answer (score 1):

Play live @ https://play.tailwindcss.com/KW66yu4vMu

You can have 1px default border or you can set custom border value as well as shown:

```html
    <div class="border-4 border-gray-900">HELLO with 4px border</div>
    <div class="border-[13px] border-gray-900">HELLO with 13px border</div>
```